# Psychisch oder Psychologisch?

Tags: semantics

In Sportlerinterviews, auf der Suche wieso es heute wieder nicht geklappt hat, wird oft von *psychologischer* Befindlichkeit gesprochen, wo es m.E. die *psychische* sein sollte.

> Wir konnten den Gegentreffer psychologisch nicht so leicht wegstecken.

*Psychologisch* wäre m.E. die Erklärung selbst mit mangelnder Frustrationstoleranz - im Gegensatz zu einer physiologischen Erklärung wie qua schlechter Laktatwerte. Die Erklärung, die sich einer Wissenschaft bedient, kann also ~*logisch* sein, aber das Erklärte selbst ist die Psyche oder die Physis, und daher muss es m.W. *psychisch* heißen.

Bin ich zu streng, und man darf beides sagen? Wenn nicht, gibt es weitere Fehlbildungen, die sich einbürgern, und diesem Muster entsprechen, wo wie die Wissenschaft von der Sache mit der Sache selbst verwechselt wird?

Comment: Ich glaube nicht, dass das ein Problem ist, das spezifisch die deutsche Sprache betrifft... Beide Wörter stammen aus dem Griechischen ab, d.h. sämtliche Sprachen, die ähnlich abgeleitete Wortpaare nutzen, hätten ein ähnliches Problem. Siehe auch die Antwort von @hanekomu - die angesprochene Verwechslung gibt es genau so auch im Englischen.

Comment: Hätten ein ähnliches Problem, oder haben sie es? Hanekomu spricht nicht über Englisch, soweit ich sehe.

Comment: Tut mir leid, auf Erbsenzählereien mag ich mich gerade nicht einlassen. Es ist Wochenende.

Comment: Tut mir leid, wenn Dir das als Erbsenzählerei erscheint - ich sehe nicht, wieso jede Sprache, die Fremdwörter aus dem griechischen entlehnt hat, undeutlich sein muss. Soll das nun speziell mit Griechisch zusammenhängen oder auch mit Latein, Französisch und Englisch? Willst Du sagen mangelnde Fremdsprachenkenntnisse sind der Grund, dass das Wort falsch benutzt wird?

Answer (score 5):

Vermutlich lässt sich im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch kein wirklicher Unterschied beschreiben, aber wenn wir kurz die Wortherkunft betrachten, so sieht man doch einen Unterschied.

"Psyche (altgriechisch ψυχή, psychḗ, für ursprünglich „Atem, Hauch“, von ψύχω, „ich atme/hauche/blase/lebe“)" - [Quelle](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psyche)

Psyche beschreibt am ehesten unsere Seele, unseren Geist oder unseren Verstand. "Psychisch" ist das entsprechende Adjektiv und bezieht sich daher auf unsere Seele. z.B. "eine psychische Erkrankung" oder "psychisch fertig sein".

Dahingegen ist "Psychologie" eine Verknüpfung von "Psyche" (Seele) und "Logos" (Wort, Lehre), steht also für die Lehre/Wissenschaft, die sich mit der Psyche beschäftigt. Strenggenommen beschreibt also das Adjektiv "psychologisch" Dinge, die mit Psychologie als Wissenschaft in Verbindung gebracht werden. z.B. "eine psychologische Sichtweise" oder "eine psychologische Untersuchungsmethode", aber eben nicht Dinge, die sich direkt auf die Seele oder den Geist beziehen.

Natürlich wird auch "psychologisch" im normalen Sprachgebrauch synonym für "psychisch" gebraucht. Für Dein Beispiel würde ich persönlich "psychisch" passender finden!

Answer (score 3):

Wenn wir uns am Duden orientieren (was ich fast immer tue), dann bist Du zu streng.

Keine Frage, *[psychisch](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/psychisch)* wäre korrekt und meines Erachtens die bessere Wahl, da es bedeutet:

> die Psyche betreffend

*[Psychologisch](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/psychologisch)* hat laut Duden drei Bedeutungen, alle lauten "die Psychologie betreffend". Das mutet auf den ersten Blick merkwürdig an, aber wenn wir uns die Erklärung für *[Psychologie](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Psychologie)* anschauen, wird die Unterscheidung deutlich:

> 1. Wissenschaft von den bewussten und unbewussten psychischen Vorgängen, vom Erleben und Verhalten des Menschen
> 2. Verständnis für, Eingehen auf die menschliche Psyche
> 3. psychische Verhaltensweise

Punkt drei, *psychische Verhaltensweise*, ist hier maßgeblich. Die Spieler konnten den Gegentreffer mit ihrer psychischen Verhaltensweise nicht so leicht wegstecken. Dieser Satz klingt so grausam, dass ich noch mal darauf hinweisen möchte, dass *psychisch* die bessere Alternative ist. (Und bevor ich nochmal zweimal "dass" in einen Satz stecke, gehe ich was essen ...)

Comment: Es beruhigt mich, dass Du den Klang als grausam empfindest. Immerhin ist es informativ zu sehen, dass man eine Autorität wie den Duden gegen sich hätte, wenn man eine Kampagne startete.

Answer (score 1):

Ich habe mich auch mit synoymem Gebrauch schwer getan. Aber mir hat folgende Überlegung geholfen:
Man möge einmal als Parallelbetrachtung das Wort "biologisch" untersuchen. Hier gibt es mit "biotisch" eine nicht ganz so gebräuchliche Parallele zu psychisch. Wenn wir von biologischen Prozessen oder Zusammenhängen sprechen, dürfte der Ersatz durch biotisch nicht so gut funktionieren. Soziologisch und sozial enthält auch eine gewisse Bedeutungsverschiebung.
Wenn wir von psychologischen Prozessen sprechen, dann meinen wir nicht etwa das, was in Forschung und Lehre in dem Fach Psychologie geschieht, sondern das, was im Menschen in Bezug zur Psyche läuft. Im gleichen Sinne würden wir hier auch von psychischen Prozessen oder Zusammenhängen sprechen.
Daher versuche ich (als studierte Psychologe) möglichst psychisch und psychologisch zu mit unterschiedlichem Inhalt zu verwenden, bin aber niemandem böse, der beide Worte synonym verwendet. "Psychologische" dürfte für die meisten Menschen einfacher auszusprechen sein als "psychische" und wird daher öfter verwendet, ist meine nur anekdotisch gestützte These.

Comment: Das Gleiche übrigens bei "physikalisch" vs. "physisch". Es wird viel öfter von "physikalisch unmöglich" gesprochen als von "physisch unmöglich", obwohl das Zweite eigentlich zutreffender wäre. Die Physik hat die Naturgesetze nicht erfunden, aber immerhin formuliert, und ähnlich sehe ich es auch in der Psychologie.

Answer (score -1):

Viele nehmen es in der Umgangssprache mit der genauen Bedeutung nicht so ernst; siehe auch "grammatikalisch" vs. "grammatisch".